# Converting code to take advantage of multiple cores

Tags: c#

I have the following question:

> Convert the following code to take advantage of your multi-core
> machine:

```
IEnumerable<double> numbers = GetNumbers();
var queue = new Queue<double>();
foreach (var number in numbers)
{
 var computed = Compute(number);
 queue.Enqueue(computed);
}
```

Comment: Replace `foreach` with `Parallel.ForEach`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Parallel.ForEach as Dialecticus suggested, you could have something like this.

```
public void PrrocessItems()
{
    IEnumerable<double> numbers = GetNumbers();
    var queue = new Queue<double>();

    Parallel.ForEach(numbers, item => ProcessItem(item, queue));
}

private void ProcessItem(double number, Queue<double> queue)
{
    var computed = Compute(number);
    queue.Enqueue(computed);
}
```

The [Parallel class of the Task Parallel Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/data-parallelism-task-parallel-library?view=netframework-4.8) takes care of breaking your collection into chunks and processing multiple iterations of your loop in parallel based on available system resources.  You don't need to manage any of the threading work yourself.